# Files created by Docker container are owned by root

Tags: permissions, docker

I've got a Docker image which generates log-like files when errors occur.  I've mounted the directory it writes to to my host machine with a bind mount.  However, the created files are owned by `root`.  Though my user account has root privileges, it is tedious to run `chown` and `chgrp` after every run of the container in order to inspect the files.

Is there a way to have the container set the owner and group of the files to that of the user who ran the container?

For some context, here's a toy example I created:

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian

WORKDIR /root
VOLUME /root/output

COPY run.sh /root/

ENTRYPOINT ["./run.sh"]
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo hello > output/dump
```

My execution command is

```
docker run -v $PWD/output:/root/output test
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The files are created by the user that runs within the container.
If your containerized command runs as `root`, then all files will be created as root.

If you want your files to be created as another user, run the container as this other user.
e.g.

```
docker run -v "$(pwd)/output":/root/output -u $(whoami) test
```

Note: Depending on your container, this might not work out of the box (e.g., because, within the container, you need to open a privileged port or your script is only accessible by a given (super)user).

Comment: So, I have to create a user with the same name inside the container?  Otherwise, the container complains that the user could not be found in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: you could also just use the (numeric) *uid* instead of the *username*. e.g. `docker run -v "$(pwd)/output":/root/output -u ${UID} test`

Comment: Passing in the UID gave `docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"./run.sh\": stat ./run.sh: permission denied": unknown.`. run.sh is executable by all.

Comment: well your `run.sh` script lives in `/root/`, and `/root/` is typically **not** readable by anyone but the superuser.

Comment: Note that `-u $(whoami)` requires that the user exists in the container. If that's not the case, you can use `-u $(id -u):$(id -g)` instead.

Comment: @Ignitor with that work around I still can't create directories inside the volume, `mkdir: cannot create directory '/emacs-install-out/system-lib': Permission denied`

Comment: sure. because the parent directory (e.g. `/emacs-install-out`) is owned by root (within the container). you have to either `chown` it (to your user(id)) or otherwise change the permissions so your user can write things to it (and you must run this as `root`)

Answer (score 6):

It's an [old known bug](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5480). As a workaround, one may use [Podman](https://podman.io/), it is compatible with Docker, they even suggest adding an `alias docker=podman`. One advantage in context of the question here is that Podman does not require a service running as root. Not only it's good for security, but it actually avoids bugs like this.

Demonstration:

```py
$ ls -l /tmp/hello
ls: cannot access 'hello': No such file or directory
$ podman run --rm -v /tmp/:/mnt/ -it ubuntu:22.04 sh -c "touch /mnt/hello && ls -l /mnt/hello"
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Sep 26 03:57 /mnt/hello
$ ls -l /tmp/hello
-rw-r--r--. 1 konstantin konstantin 0 сен 26 06:57 hello
```